# How to login on php

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am trying to create logins for users. I have an sql that inserts the information in a mysql database, but after that i don't know how to actually start the login.  As of now, I insert the information on join_action.php which then redirects to /index.php (below).  Does `session_start()` on /index.php actually start the login?  Becuase if so, it's not working.

PHP (join_action.php):

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$name','$password','$email','$date','$time','$random','0','1','0')");
            $id=mysql_insert_id();
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;



            header("Location: http://localhost/index.php");
```

HTML (index.php top):

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
```

Comment: Not directly related to your problem but make sure to check out SQL Injection attacks. Your code is potentially vulnerable.

Comment: @tangrs took care of it.  thanks

Comment: No, that's not what it does. By itself. Also unclear how the account creation SQL is related to the logins. See the manual on: [`session_start`](http://php.net/session_start). And be sure to google some tutorials on PHP and creating login schemes first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

login.php (untested, but should give you the right idea)

```
<?
   @session_start();
   if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $name = addslashes({$_POST['login']});
    $password = addslashes({$_POST['password']});
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '{$name}' AND password = '{$password}'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0) {
      $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
      $_SESSION['user'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
     } else {
      $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 0;
      $_SESSION['user'] = null;
     }
    }

    if($_SESSION['loggedin']==1) {
?>
    Logged in! 
    <pre><? print_r($_SESSION['user]); ?></pre>
<? } else { ?>
    Not logged in...<br>
    <form method='post' action='login.php'>
    <div>Login: <input type='text' name='login'></div>
    <div>Password: <input type='password' name='password'></div>
    <input type='submit' value='Log In'>
    </form>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: so the actual action that did the logging in was setting session variables?

Comment: addslashes will not protect from sql injections

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the question was not about SQL injections

Comment: @user802370 You have to query for existing users with the right login / email combination, then setup a session variable defining whether they are logged in or not, and if they are, a user variable in the session so you can access the user information.

Answer (score 2):

Download any number of open source projects and see how they handle logins.

No, session_start() doesn't directly handle the login, it's just starting a new session which MIGHT be used by the login script.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start` will initialize the PHP session for the page, but you don't appear to have any code to actually manipulate them like setting them or checking their validity or anything else, so it'll basically do nothing. It doesn't magically know what you want to DO with your session. All you've got is one line to set an ID.

Comment: other than criticizing my code, do you have anything that will help the problem

Comment: Hardly criticizing, I answered your question `Does session_start() on /index.php actually start the login?` and explained why not. What you can do is then set the session values you need, and check them at the top of every page to ensure the user has logged in properly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to code a little extra in order to start using `session_start()`. To begin, `session_start()` simply begins a PHP session where the server begins tracking that particular user. In your methodology, you'll need to link that session to user data in your code.

When I was learning PHP users, this handy script really helped me understand the methodology: http://www.majordojo.com/php-users/

Although it's in PHP4, it's very similar code. :)